# How to include SVG within an SVG document which has JavaScript code?

Tags: svg

*Please understand this question properly before marking as duplicate.*

There are many questions like this one in ***StackOverflow***, but my question is slightly different from those.

I have a *chakra.svg* file, whose code is this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" id="b">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" stroke-width="2" stroke="blue" fill="none"/>
    <script>
        <![CDATA[
            for(i=0;i<24;i++)
            {
                var l=document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","line");
                l.setAttributeNS(null,"x1","50");
                l.setAttributeNS(null,"y1","50");
                l.setAttributeNS(null,"x2","5");
                l.setAttributeNS(null,"y2","50");
                l.setAttributeNS(null,"stroke-width",2);
                l.setAttributeNS(null,"stroke","blue");
                l.setAttributeNS(null,"transform","rotate("+(i/24*360)+",50,50)");
                document.querySelector("#b").appendChild(l);
            }
        ]]>
    </script>
</svg>
```

The output is rendered as expected, like this:
[image]

I have another file, *India_flag.svg* whose code is this:

```
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="170" height="100">
    <rect x="0" y="0" height="33" width="180" fill="#f93"/>
    <rect x="0" y="33" height="34" width="180" fill="white"/>
    <rect x="0" y="67" height="33" width="180" fill="green"/>
</svg>
```

The output of this file is also rendered as expected:
[image]

But, now the problem is, when I am trying to insert the *chakra.svg* file inside the *India_flag.svg* file using the ***image*** tag like this:

```
<image xlink:href="chakra.svg" x="70" y="35" height="30" width="30"/>
```

The output should have been that the wheel is placed at the centre of the flag, but I am getting this output:
[image]

The *chakra.svg* file is rendered, but the JavaScript code in that file did not run, only the circle is rendered. What am I doing wrong and how to achieve my objective?

Comment: Have you defined (or imported) your javascript before your code? :-)

Comment: How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

SVG documents when loaded inside an `<image>` tag (or HTML `<img>` for that matter) are sand-boxed and won't allow the execution of scripts, nor will they be interactive (i.e no user-event).

To circumvent that, you need an other way to append you svg. The simple solution would be to copy its markup directly in the main one:

```html
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="170" height="100">
  <rect x="0" y="0" height="33" width="180" fill="#f93"/>
  <rect x="0" y="33" height="34" width="180" fill="white"/>
  <rect x="0" y="67" height="33" width="180" fill="green"/>
  <svg x="70" y="35" height="30" width="30" id="b" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" stroke-width="2" stroke="blue" fill="none"/>
    <script>
      <![CDATA[
        for(i=0;i<24;i++) {
          var l=document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","line");
          l.setAttribute("x1","50");
          l.setAttribute("y1","50");
          l.setAttribute("x2","5");
          l.setAttribute("y2","50");
          l.setAttribute("stroke-width",2);
          l.setAttribute("stroke","blue");
          l.setAttribute("transform","rotate("+(i/24*360)+",50,50)");
          document.querySelector("#b").appendChild(l);
        }
      ]]>
    </script>
  </svg>
</svg>
```

An other solution, would have been to do the inverse: load your flag image from the one with the script: [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/SU1MUD6jbPIwBbctSzQw?p=preview).

Comment: Yes that was a bad idea sorry use don't allow script execution either, edited since then.

Comment: @Ruturaj said something about importing JavaScript before the code. What is it and how to do that?

Comment: No offense whatsoever, but I fear they simply don't know what they are talking about and thrown some random words in a sentence.

Comment: So, is there no way of doing what I want, that is, including a SVG document inside another SVG document along with the running JavaScript code?

Comment: Well the code in my answer does that. It could be automated by js if you need. And iIf you absolutely need it to be an external svg, then you'd have to resort on using a `<foreignObject>` that would host an html `<iframe>` that would load your file.

Comment: Thanks for the <foreignObject> idea.

Comment: I had inserted an <iframe src="chakra.svg"> inside the <foreignObject> tag, but it isn't showing the full wheel. There are scrollbars in the iframe and I need to scroll it to see the whole wheel. Anyway, thanks for all your ideas, I will try to manage it somehow.